# Dialog Table Name Prompt Error In MapBasic_Mapbasic

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I am trying to prompt the Table name from the opened tables and to use it in the rest of the program, but what i get is (Table (i) is not open) after clicking ok
the Sub Procedure is below, please help

```
Sub Selection

Dim num_open_Tabs, Ix  As Integer    
Dim Tab_names(50) As string
Dim Sector_table as string
Dim Sector_Table_Name as String 
Dim sector_Table_Obj as Object

Win_ID = FrontWindow()
num_open_Tabs = NumTables() 'Create Array of the Layers Names

Redim Tab_Names(num_open_Tabs)  
For Ix = 1 to num_open_Tabs
   Tab_names(ix) = TableINFO(Ix, Tab_INFO_NAME)
Next

Dialog 'Prompt the wanted Layer name
   Title "Choose Cell_Data Table"
   Control StaticText    
      Position 10,10 Width 250 Height 10
      ID 1
      Title "Please Choose The Table Containing Your Sector Info"    

   Control popupmenu
      Title From Variable Tab_names
      Position 10,20 Width 250 Height 15
      Id 2
      Value Sector_table    
      Into Sector_table
   Control StaticText
      Position 10,50 
      Title "Enter Buffer Width"

   Control EditText
      Position 10, 60
      Value "200"
      Into Sel_Width
   Control OKButton
   Control CancelButton

If CommandInfo (CMD_INFO_DLG_OK) then
   Sector_Table_Name = TableInfo(Sector_Table, TAB_INFO_NAME)
Else 
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this dim:

```
Dim Sector_table as string
```

to:

```
Dim Sector_table as Integer
```

Also you can get to the name of the table using the array of tables that you already have created:

```
Sector_Table_Name = Tab_names(Sector_Table)
```

And a final suggestion is not to use Selection as a name of a procedure. Selection is the name of the current selection and this might confuse your application at some stage - or yourself.